# Docker ubuntu image with web server installed explicitly vs docker web server image?

Tags: image, docker, nginx, containers

What is the difference between Docker os image with web server installed with a web server and Docker webserver image ?
For eg Docker image of Ubuntu-16.04 running as container with NginX installed and other container running Nginx as Nginx Docker image?
Whose Performance will be better and stable ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a container with nginx runs in alpine os . a very lightweight os. While in the other hand you have ubuntu os and nginx. 
So , the difference? ... the OS.

Comment: better?  depends on your needs. Stable? I'll say both are. But following containers-based [https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/cloud-native-container-design-whitepaper] principles ... the one with alpine will be in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have good Docker/Unix/shell-scripting skills, a continuous-integration (CI) system, and the willingness to do ongoing maintenance, you might prefer building your own images.  You will be in control of the exact version of the software used, and any build options or extensions required, and you will control when it gets security patches.  But, this is a harder path to get started with, and if you don't periodically update your custom images they'll never get any sort of bug fixes or security patches at all.

If you're new to this space, you might prefer standard Docker Hub images.  They're pre-packaged, usually have "enough" customization options, and are generally fairly good quality.  But, if you need some extra customization, you might wind up needing to build a custom image anyways.  I've also run into a situation where I've pinned an image to a specific upstream version `image:1.2.3`, and noticed several months later that `image:1.2.7` is out, and the six-month-old Docker Hub image hasn't gotten a critical security fix because it's not getting built any more.

If none of this especially concerns you (and if you don't have a DevOps team at your disposal), I'd suggest just using the prebuilt `nginx` image and focusing on building and deploying your actual application.